# Is there any MFCC library can be used in android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, mfcc

My team is making a emotion-recognition in speech app.

To get mfcc, we use comirva package.

The problem is that AudioInputStream needed to create AudioPreProcessor can't be used in android.

So we have been finding some kind of alternative.

Is there any way to get mfcc in android?

Comment: did you able to build the comirva package in android platform?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace AudioInputStream with just InputStream in comirva sources, it's a trivial modification. AudioInputStream purepose is just to store and manage stream format, the MFCC computation doesn't need it, it can process the raw data.

Comment: I replaced the AudioInputStream with java.io.InputStream but how to get the  getFormat, getSampleSizeInBits, getSampleSizeInBits? :(